# UPDATE em todos os registros, alterando número do autoincrement

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uns 500 registros no banco de dados, com autoincrement em uma tabela começando no 900,901,902 em diante, teria como fazer um UPDATE em todos os registros começando o autoincrement no número 502?

Ai todos registros passam a ter ID autoincrement 502,503,504, em diante ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET  @num := 0;

UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);

ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Resolvido

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tabela;
[COPIE O CODIGO E EXECUTE APOS O COMANDO DO RENAME]
RENAME TABLE tabela TO tabela_old;
INSERT INTO tabela (
[DESCREVA TODOS OS CAMPOS MENOS O ID]
)
SELECT
    [TODOS OS CAMPOS MENOS O ID]
FROM tabela_old;
```

Cerifique-se que os dados estão corretos e delete a tabela old.

Prefiro fazer dessa maneira, para não rodar um update direto na tabela e perder alguns dados. e também aconselho fazer um backup dos dados e verificar se essa tabela que você está alterando não faz referência com nenhuma outra, se não você vai perder referências